# Is there a way to save what buttons are pressed into a text file

Tags: tkinter

I was wondering whether anyone knows how to save button clicks into a text file. For example if a button which has the text "hello" on it, is pressed; it then saves that in a text file to show that the "hello" button was pressed

Comment: if you use `command=` or `bind()` with every button then you can assign some function to do it.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is nothing built in. You'll have to add custom bindings.

You could, for example, add a class binding on the `Button` class. For example:

```
root.bind_class("Button", "<ButtonPress-1>", log_buttonpress, add="+")
```

You can then define a method called `log_buttonpress` which looks something like this:

```
def log_buttonpress(self, event):
    with open("/tmp/log.txt", "a+") as f:
        f.write("=> " + event.widget.cget("text") + "\n")
```

Of course, this will only capture clicks with the mouse. It won't capture buttons clicked using the keyboard. Also, the command for the button isn't called until you release the button so this might log buttons that were clicked on but not actually activated. These problems are solvable, but require more code. This just shows the general concept, not a cut-and-paste solution.

Another way to create your own subclass of `Button` and add this special binding to each instance. Through the use of bind tags you can add a special tag to every instance, and then you just have to have a single binding for that tag.

For example:

```
class MyButton(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Button.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        bindtags = list(self.bindtags())
        bindtags.insert(1, "MyButton")
        self.bindtags(tuple(bindtags))

    @classmethod
    def log_button(cls, event):
        with open("/tmp/junk.txt", "a+") as f:
            f.write("?> " + event.widget.cget("text") + "\n")

...
root = tk.Tk()
root.bind_class("MyButton", "<ButtonRelease-1>", MyButton.log_button)

b1 = MyButton(...)
b2 = MyButton(...)
```

Comment: Thank you:) this helped me so much:)